# MigraDoc RTF Document cannot translate special characters

Tags: c#, .net, rtf, migradoc

I created an application, where we want to create .rtf & .pdf Documents.
The documents also contain characters like ä,ü,ö,ß and we have the big issue, that those special characters are not shown correctly in the RTF Document.

For creating the rtf document, we are using "Migradoc" and the "RtfDocumentRenderer".

The PDF will be created correctly... And for the rtf document, we already tried a few things:

- Setting the UTF encoding before calling the renderer
- changing the culture info
- creating the document as byte array, converting it to an array, encoded the byte array, but without success
- with Unicode instead of the character.

Comment: Update:
The issue is, that the new .net 7 application uses a different default encoding... If you try it with a project with version 4.8 (Encoding.1252) everything works. And the new project (UTF-8 and net 7) does not work correctly.

Comment: There is a new release of PDFsharp/MigraDoc in the queue that will target .NET 6 and should resolve that issue even with .NET 7. Cannot give an ETA yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version 1.51 of PDFsharp/MigraDoc targets .NET 2.0/.NET 3.5. Special characters work with .NET Framework versions up to 4.x.

The next version of PDFsharp (preview versions of 6.0.0 have already been published) targets .NET 6 and properly deals with the change of the default encoding.

Comment: Do you already know, when the version will be released? and is there a beta/alpha what I can test..?

Answer (score 0):

With the newest version, it is possible to use special language characters as well. (Version PDFsharp-MigraDoc 6.0.0-preview-2 )